# Lines after Closure didn't run

Tags: swift, async-await, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

some lines of my code are not running

```
   func createaddress() async {
        do {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            guard let userid = defaults.string(forKey: "userid") else { return }
           let response = try await Amplify.API.mutate(request:
                .createUserAddress(bycreateUserAddressPayload: address, addressName: addressName, isDefault: isDefault, landmark: landmark, userId:  "USR- \(userid)", city: city, state: state)
           )
            switch response {
            case .success(let Result):
//                    print(graphQLResult)
                if let JSONdata = Result.value(at: "createUserAddress"),
                    let todoData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(JSONdata),
                   let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(UserAddressResponse.self, from: todoData) {
                    print(response.userAddress.id)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.Loading = false
                    }
                }
               
                
            case.failure(let error):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.Loading = false
                    self.showerrormessage = true
                    self.errormessage = "Failed to Create Address"
                    
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                    self.showerrormessage = false
                    self.errormessage = ""
                }
                print("Failed to get  UserAddressData: \(error)")
            }
        } catch let error as APIError {
            print("Failed to query CreateUserAddress: \(error)")
        } catch {
            print("Unexpected error CreateUserAddress: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

[image]

the code in the closure  after  "let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(UserAddressResponse.self, from: todoData)" from line 440 to 442 did not run

Comment: Don't use `try?` Use `try` inside a `do/catch` and add `print(error)` inside the `catch`. Then you will know why it is failing.

Comment: It's  giving  me error
1. Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Data'
2. Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UserAddressResponse'

Comment: That's a whole new issue caused by your code changes from `try?` to `try`. The two `try` lines can't be part of the `if let` line any more.

Comment: should I change it to guard let then

Comment: The lines are not executed because either `JSONdata` is nil or one of your Json operation fails. What is the reason behind encoding `JSONdata` and decoding it right back? This seems pointless and may be the reason behind all this. Of what type is `JSONdata`?

Comment: That’s how it’s done in the aws amplify documentation

Answer (score 0):

Before you can diagnose the problem, you first need to first make sure you report what the error is. The challenge is that you have a few categories of problems where you currently silently fail with no diagnostic information:

1. The two `try?` statements will silently return `nil` if either fails, and thereby will discard meaningful diagnostic information. Use `try` (without the `if let` or `guard let`, because it is no longer an optional) and let your `catch` clause will now report what went wrong.
2. If the `result.value(at: …)` failed and returned `nil`, `if` statement will not be satisfied and it will not report anything meaningful.
3. It probably is not relevant to the immediate problem, but if you do not find a userid in `UserDefaults`, you just `return` with nothing to let you know why no address record was created.

So, you might, instead, want to do something like:

```swift
switch response {
case .success(let result):
    guard let jsonData = result.value(at: "createUserAddress") else {
        print("createUserAddress not found")                            // better, I would create new error regarding “value(at:) failed”, and throw that error, but I am trying to keep it as simple as possible
        return
    }
    let todoData = try JSONEncoder().encode(jsonData)
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserAddressResponse.self, from: todoData) 
    print(response.userAddress.id)
    …
    
case.failure(let error):
    …
}
```

Because we use `try` instead of `try?`, we remove those from the `if let` clause, but the `catch` clause will report the error on the console. Likewise, we print a message if the `value(at:)` failed for some reason, you now will be notified of the problem.

(As an aside, `JSONDecoder` method `decode` does not take a trailing closure, so I have removed that. Likewise, I have conformed to Swift variable naming conventions of starting with a lowercase letter. But neither of these are terribly relevant to the question at hand, so don’t get distracted by that. But I wanted to explain some of these unrelated changes included in my code snippet above.)

Anyway, now that (a) you are printing a message if `value(at:)` failed; and (b) allowing `try` to throw any errors if encoding/decoding failed, you should be able to now diagnose why execution is not proceeding. So run the code again and see what error is produced.

And if you are unclear what the new runtime errors mean, then post a separate question on that (but feel free to include a link to your new, separate question in comments; but avoid editing your existing question, which is effectingly “why is it silently failing”). But hopefully the above answers the question why you are currently not getting any diagnostic information regarding what is going wrong at runtime.

Personally, I am guessing that there is a JSON decoding problem (some key name is incorrect, or what have you), but until you start printing the actual error thrown by `try`, this is mere guesswork.

---

Now, there are a ton of additional refinements that I might advise, but they aren’t related to the immediate problem (that you have paths of execution that will silently fail without any diagnostic information). But if you are interested in additional observations, please let me know.